# What's the difference between parse trees and abstract syntax trees?

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, parse-tree

I found the two terms in a compiler design book, and I'd like to know what each stands for, and how they are different.

I searched on the internet and found that parse trees are also called concrete syntax trees (CSTs).